# How to write TODO lists in vim

Tags: vim

I'm looking for how to use TODO list in vim editor. I used `command Todo noautocmd vimgrep /TODO\|FIXME/j ** | cw` in my `.vimrc` file. I'm wondering how to invoke it to see the `TODO` list

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That command defines an *alias* for the built-in `:vimgrep` command. As the command does not take any arguments (the `:vimgrep` operates on all files, recursing into subdirs: `**`), you just invoke it with `:Todo`. You'll see progress, and the *quickfix list* will automatically open `:cw` with the results (i.e. all lines containing either `TODO` or `FIXME`).